# Batch installing packages script in Octave

Tags: performance, strings, error-handling, installer, octave

I am attempting to write a light script to deal with multiple package installation in Octave. The available packages can be checked in [Octave Forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/packages.php) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#Packages). For example, if the packages `data-smoothing`, `fuzzy-logic toolkit`, `image`, `image-acquisition`, `parallel`, `statistics` and `video` are needed to be installed, list these package names into `Packages` collection, such as:

```
Packages{1} = "data-smoothing";
Packages{2} = "fuzzy-logic toolkit";
Packages{3} = "image";
Packages{4} = "image-acquisition";
Packages{5} = "parallel";
Packages{6} = "statistics";
Packages{7} = "video";
```

Then pass it into `InstallPackages` function.

```
InstallPackages(Packages);
```

**The experimental implementation**

```
function [] = InstallPackages(Packages)
  for i = 1:size(Packages, 2)
    try
      fprintf("Package %s is about to be installed!\n", Packages{1, i});
      pkg('install', '-forge', Packages{1, i});
    catch (exception)
      fprintf("Package %s installation failed!\n", Packages{1, i});
    end
  endfor
end
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You don’t need `eval`, you can just do `pkg('install', '-forge', Packages{1, i})`

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thank you for the suggestion. Already updated.